# Android Java Code : Convert column values in to rows?

Tags: android

I have a table value in sqlite like..

```
101 Local Local Local   Local   Local   Local
102 9     12    9       12      9       9
  1 3:55    4:20    4:40    5:00    5:20    5:40
 18 4:50    5:15    5:35    5:55    6:15    6:35
```

Above value i need to store in
ArrayList> listData = new ArrayList>(); 
or some other arrays

```
 Local  9   3:55    4:50
 Local  12  4:20    5:15
 Local  9   4:40    5:35
 Local  12  5:00    5:55
 Local  9   5:20    6:15
 Local  9   5:40    6:35
```

plz help me to find :)

Comment: Please format your table representation properly.  I can't even figure out what your table looks like, and that's before I try to figure out what question you are asking.

Comment: Simon its a very huge table.. So i cant modified that.. So i want to solve this in code :)

Comment: I meant, format your question properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to create a domain/container-object for your table entitys.

```
public class TableEntity {
  private int col1;
  private String col2;
  private String col3;

  // generate getters and setters...
}
```

Then by reading the values of you sqlite table create the new object and return the ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<TableEntity> lAllTableEntitys = new ArrayList<TableEntity>();
while(cursor.moveToNext()){
TableEntity tableEntity = new TableEntity();
tableEntity.setCol1(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("col1")));
tableEntity.setCol2(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("col2")));
tableEntity.setCol3(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("col3")));
lAllTableEntitys.add(tableEntity);
}
return lAllTableEntitys;
```

after that you can read it easily with

```
tableEntity.getCol1();
tableEntity.getCol2();
tableEntity.getCol3();
```